# deserialize issue json xamarin

Tags: json, xamarin

Why on gods earth will the `APFile.Id` not deserialize correct ???

I have a simple class `APFile` - which I try to deserialize - for some reason it will not deserialize the `Id` - and I cannot see where its going wrong :(

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace ActionShared
{
[Serializable]
public class APFile
{
    public APFile()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// File id
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The id of entity that the file is attached to.
    /// </summary>
//  [JsonProperty("type")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The file name including the extension.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("filename")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The mime type of the file.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Mimetype { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The size of the file in bytes.
    /// </summary>
    //[JsonProperty("size")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Size { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The unique id of the file creator's profile.
    /// </summary>
    //[JsonProperty("creator_id")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Creator { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The unique id of the file creator's profile.
    /// </summary>
    //[JsonProperty("creator_name")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string CreatorName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The date and time when the file was uploaded.
    /// </summary>
//  [JsonProperty("created_at")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The date and time when the file was last updated.
    /// </summary>
//  [JsonProperty("updated_at")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// A link to download the file.
    /// </summary>
    //[JsonProperty("url")]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
}

public void Do()
{
    string a = "{\"id\":910,\"filename\":\"image.jpg\"}";
    var b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APFile>(a);
    // b.Id = 0 and b.Filename = "image.jpg"
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend using http://jsonutils.com/ against your json response to generate your classes. You might find that your type is incorrect and defaulting to 0.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here. Try removing other fields and just keep id and filename to check. My suggestion though

Comment: I did a cut/paste and that code definitely works for me and I get a populated `b` with Id = 910

Comment: Thanks a lot on every comment - thought I was going mental - it must something in my environment then - it happens in a shared xamarin library

Comment: @TheSnakeWizard Using Newtonsoft.Json? (v8.0.3 in my case)

Answer (score 0):

plz copy your json responce and convert into C# class file to http://json2csharp.com/

```
public home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

            PostRequest(this, "http://propertyworld.in/app/property.php?");
        }



public async static void PostRequest(home instance, string URL)
        {
            var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
             {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("action", "property_list"),
            });
            var myHttpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = await myHttpClient.PostAsync(URL, formContent);
           //json variable is over responce
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            MyJsonConvertedclass record = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyJsonConvertedclass>(json);

            ObservableCollection<ModelClass.infoClass> ls = new ObservableCollection<ModelClass.infoClass> { };
            foreach (var point in record.records)
            {
                ls.Add(new ModelClass.infoClass
                {
                    info1 = Stringclass.rs + " " + point.property.price,
                    info2 = point.property.title.ToUpper(),
                    url = record.image_url + point.property.image
                });
            }

            instance.newProp.ItemsSource = ls;
//instance.yourControllname which is declares in your xaml like 

        }
```